# Adding Variable in JSon Its Not Working

Tags: php, json

i am trying to add variable in json variable then try to send email i am getting variable not Variable Value please take a look :

```
$request_json = '{
           "type":"messages",
           "call":"send",
           "message":{
              "html":"$salesmsgUpdatemsg",
              }'; 

$request_json = '{
           "type":"messages",
           "call":"send",
           "message":{
              "html":"'.$salesmsgUpdatemsg.'",
              }';
```

Both codes not working if i use

```
$request_json = '{
           "type":"messages",
           "call":"send",
           "message":{
              "html":"Content Text",
              }';
```

Its working fine.

No idea what happen.

Thanks

Comment: You should not build your json manually. Build an array / object the way you want it and use `json_encode()`.

Comment: But it's mandrill Json

Comment: First one with single quotes won't interpolate PHP variables.

Comment: What if the variable contains a double quote? That will break your json.

Comment: I already try with double quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow [jeoren advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347490/adding-variable-in-json-its-not-working/24347552#comment37643103_24347490) because one day your code **will** break.

```
$request = array ('type'=>"messages",
                  'call'=>'send',
                  'message'=>array(
                        'html'=>$salesmsgUpdatemsg
                ));

$request_json = json_encode($request);
```